# how to supress AssertionError displaying in testng report in selenium

Tags: selenium, testng

I get the below error in console and in report as well. But I don't want this error trace to be displayed in report. How to suppress this error that is getting displayed in report?
I am calling this function Library.Test() with a custom fail message:
My code is:

```
AssertJUnit.assertTrue("FAIL: Please check the logs in report. Either there are no more than 10 records and there is a problem in application.",Library.Test());
```

My AssertionError trace as follows:

```
FAILED: TC
java.lang.AssertionError: FAIL: Please check the logs in report. Either there are no more than 10 records and there is a problem in application.
  at org.testng.AssertJUnit.fail(AssertJUnit.java:59)
  at org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertTrue(AssertJUnit.java:24)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
  at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
  at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: You can use Exception handling concepts.

Comment: I have used try and catch block in Test() method. But when ever test fails, this particular message displays in report as well.

Comment: Any exceptions will be in the report. Your solution would be to write that message to a log file.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that until now there seems to be no way to configure reporters via the XML file.

Right now, this is only possible by passing the `-reporter` command line parameter to TestNG:

`-reporter org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter:stackTraceOutputMethod=0[,additional=param]`

The accepted parameters can be found in the  [TestNG Logger Config documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-xml-reports).

Per default it outputs the complete stacktrace, but you can configure any length of stacktrace in the report. 
Setting the configuration parameter "stackTraceOutputMethod" to 0 will output only Exception class and message, which sounds like the bevahior you are looking for.

If you need to tweak the reporting more you might have a look at the [Reporter API](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporter-api).

Comment: hey thanks. I tried to get help on configuring "stackTraceOutputMethod" to 0 in testng.xml. but I didnt get any help on net. I dont know how to configure. I went through the link you provided, but not able to understand how can I configure. Please help me how to set this property?

Comment: I found out that until now tehre seems to be no way to configure reporters via the XML file.

Comment: Fixed the answer to show correct way to configure the reporter. I did find the value format for reporter by digging into ReporterConfig.deserialize. The TestNG documentation could be improved here IMHO.